# Cannot resolve issue in Android automation using appium, Java in Android Studio

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, junit, appium-android

[image]

I did not find any answers so far, I did try to clean project and rebuild, synchronize and invalid caches restart, SDK.......options. I installed and uninstall all framework many times The following error is displaying  is saying error

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
target Compatibility = '1.7' (I did this changes )
source Compatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build .gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app: transform Classes With Dex For Debug.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: **DesiredCapabilities** ,Capabilities,**By**.id are always turning into red color

Comment: can you post the logs or screenshot ?

Comment: Putting things like "urgent" or "ASAP" into the question is usually contra-productive. You are talking to volunteers that help you in their free time without getting paid.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Henry and Halfer. I will do

Comment: I will provide ASAP @Manidroid

Comment: @manidroid I just update my question could you please suggest me any solution. I think it is selenium web driver is not installed properly. I am using java 1.7 and android latest version and appium 1.22 webdriver 3.5.3 and java client 5.0.3 jar
Regards
Narendar